# How to add 1 to function every second?

Tags: php

I have a function called $function. I want my code to add 1 to $function every second, and in "live".

```
$function = 100;
$add = $function + 1;

echo $add;
```

How do I run/execute $add every second? I would like to see the number getting bigger in "live" (without having to refresh the page every time I want to see the result).

Comment: that's not how php works.use JS to update the number on your client.

Comment: Yeah, you're not going to get that particular type of functionality without some type of ServerSideNotification or WebSocket setup. Alternatively, use native javascript to mutate the DOM - much easier

Comment: How can I do this? Do you have a code that would do that (I don't know JS :-/ )?

Comment: Also, how is $function even a function?

Answer (score 1):

PHP is a **server-side** language which can only actually do anything on your server. If you want things to update dynamically on the *client* (i.e. your browser) you need a **client-side** language, like JavaScript. Generally server-side languages like PHP generate client-side code which is then transferred over a network to your browser.

For example, you could get your PHP server to output the following HTML:

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div id="number">1</div>
        <script>
            var text = document.getElementById("number");
            var number = 1;

            window.setInterval(function() {
                // code in here will repeat every 1000ms
                number = number + 1;
                text.innerText = number;
            }, 1000);
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you're just learning to program, you might enjoy learning **HTML** and **JavaScript** more, without worrying about the server for now, as you can get to see the results of your program more dynamically. A good resource might be [Codecademy](https://www.codecademy.com/tracks/javascript) or direct from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Learn/JavaScript)

Comment: Thanks for answering :-) I tried the code but it only shows "1" so I added "document.write(number);" in the window.setInterval. When I launch it I get "1", and than "2", but than the page keeps loading and nothing more happens. Is this normal?

Comment: That doesn't sound right, no. The line `text.innerText = number;` should take care of updating the number, so document.write shouldn't be necessary. JSFiddle.net is a good place to play with these things - it separates JavaScript (functionality), HTML (structure) and CSS (style). Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/hephistocles/ggx9w34e/